# Generate Torrent from Bucket via Go SDK (Amazon S3)

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

I'm trying to figure out a way to generate torrent files from a bucket, using the AWS SDK for Go.

I'm using a pre-signed url (since its a private bucket):

```
svc := s3.New(session.New(config))
    req, _ := svc.GetObjectRequest(&s3.GetObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String("bucketName"),
        Key:    "key",
    })
    // sign the url
    url, err := req.Presign(120 * time.Minute)
```

From the docs, to generate a torrent, the syntax:

```
GET /ObjectName?torrent HTTP/1.1
Host: BucketName.s3.amazonaws.com
Date: date
Authorization: authorization string
```

How do I add the `?torrent` parameter to a presigned url in GO?

Answer (score 1):

Try `GetOBjectTorrent` method on the AWS Go SDK. It will return you `.torrent` file in response, here is example code:

```
svc := s3.New(session.New())
input := &s3.GetObjectTorrentInput{
    Bucket: aws.String("bucketName"),
    Key:    aws.String("key"),
}

result, _ := svc.GetObjectTorrent(input)
fmt.Println(result)
```

Please see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/#S3.GetObjectTorrent for more details. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the input, does this work for private objects?